# In xmlpullparser, value changes when you call multiple times getEventType

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

When I run multiple times.
I understand that the value of the "xpp.next()" is changed.

However, I do not understand that the value of the "xpp.getEventType()" is also changed.

When you step in the debugger, it was found that the value changes.

If not Break, value did not change.

Why the value is going to be changed?

```
       package com.example.xmlpulltestapp;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.StringReader;

   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

   public class SimpleXmlPull
   {
        public static void main() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(data));

        int event = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 0 Eclipse Break
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 1
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 2
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 3
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 4
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 5
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 6
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 7
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 8
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 9
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 10
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 11
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 12
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 13
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 14
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 15
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 16
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 17
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 18
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 19
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 20
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 21
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 22
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 23
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 24
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 25
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 26
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 27
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 28
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 29
        event = xpp.getEventType(); log(event, cnt++); // 30
    }

    static String data ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" 
                + "<ttFont sfntVersion=\"\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\" ttLibVersion=\"2.4\">"
                +   "<cmap>"
                +       "<tableVersion version=\"0\"/>"
                +       "<cmap_format_4 platformID=\"0\" platEncID=\"3\" language=\"0\">"
                +           "<map code=\"0x20\" name=\"space\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x21\" name=\"exclam\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x22\" name=\"quotedbl\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x23\" name=\"numbersign\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x24\" name=\"dollar\"/>"
                +       "</cmap_format_4>"
                +       "<cmap_format_6 platformID=\"1\" platEncID=\"0\" language=\"0\">"
                +           "<map code=\"0x20\" name=\"space\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x21\" name=\"exclam\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x22\" name=\"quotedbl\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x23\" name=\"numbersign\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x24\" name=\"dollar\"/>"
                +       "</cmap_format_6>"
                +       "<cmap_format_4 platformID=\"3\" platEncID=\"1\" language=\"0\">"
                +           "<map code=\"0x20\" name=\"space\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x21\" name=\"exclam\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x22\" name=\"quotedbl\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x23\" name=\"numbersign\"/>"
                +           "<map code=\"0x24\" name=\"dollar\"/>"
                +       "</cmap_format_4>"
                +   "</cmap>"
                + "</ttFont>";


  }
```

This is a log of when you step to Break in Eclipse.
value of eventtype will change but not running the next.

```
03-22 09:35:06.043: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=0
03-22 09:35:06.643: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=1
03-22 09:35:07.223: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=2
03-22 09:35:07.823: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=3
03-22 09:35:08.303: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=4
03-22 09:35:08.803: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=5
03-22 09:35:09.303: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=6
03-22 09:35:09.803: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=7
03-22 09:35:10.293: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=8
03-22 09:35:10.773: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=9
03-22 09:35:11.233: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=10
03-22 09:35:11.663: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=11
03-22 09:35:12.123: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=12
03-22 09:35:12.613: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=13
03-22 09:35:13.103: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=14
03-22 09:35:13.563: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=15
03-22 09:35:14.083: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=16
03-22 09:35:14.623: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=17
03-22 09:35:15.053: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=18
03-22 09:35:15.533: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=19
03-22 09:35:16.003: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=20
03-22 09:35:16.483: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=21
03-22 09:35:17.433: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=22
03-22 09:35:17.903: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=23
03-22 09:35:18.353: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=24
03-22 09:35:18.833: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=25
03-22 09:35:19.323: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=26
03-22 09:35:19.853: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=27
03-22 09:35:20.703: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=28
03-22 09:35:21.903: I/System.out(3548): EventType=3 Cnt=29
03-22 09:35:22.723: I/System.out(3548): EventType=2 Cnt=30
```

This is a log of when you do not do step execution.
Value of eventType does not change.

```
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=0
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=1
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=2
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=3
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=4
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=5
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=6
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=7
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=8
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=9
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=10
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=11
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=12
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=13
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=14
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=15
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=16
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=17
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=18
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=19
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=20
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=21
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=22
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=23
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=24
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=25
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=26
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=27
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=28
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=29
03-22 09:35:52.473: I/System.out(3605): EventType=2 Cnt=30
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Can you please elaborate? If youre simply wondering why `getEventType()` changes, it will be different every time you call `next()`, otherwise, I have no clue what you want.

Comment: When you run in the debugger Step of eclipse, I did not know that the value of getEventType changes when not to call the Next () is why.

Answer (score 0):

The `getEventType()` method returns a static variable depending on the section of XML it is currently parsing. The same is also true for the `next()` method which is essentially the same as the `getEventType()` method and may explain why the value changes. It is not intended to be called multiple times in the way that you have implemented it. As you can see from the following code you can switch action based on the `getEventType()`/`next()` method return value:

```
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) { // Keep iterating unless the current eventType is the end of the document
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) { // Switch action based on the current eventType value
        System.out.println("Start document");
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xpp.next(); // Set the current event type from the return value of next()
}
```